Approximate power analysis for simple linear mixed model without random effects
For educational purposes, a repeated measure of all participants in two conditions is modeled as linear mixed model. We're interested in the difference in outcome while controlling for confounders $c_1$ and $c_2$. Only fixed effects are of interest while random effects are completely negligible (and de facto zero):
model <- 'outcome ~ condition + c1 + c2 + (1 | id)'

A sophisticated power analysis by simulation (as recommended for LMMs) isn't feasible in our context. So how can I accomplish a very rough (and maybe conservative) estimation of power that just needs a few parameters (as usually used in G*Power for example) like effect size $f^2$, error, and $1-β$ probabilities instead of a plethora of other parameters?
Edit: just to clarify, it's no time-lagged measurement, repeated measure refers to the fact that all participants got tested in two different conditions (a lab test, 5 minutes between conditions, therefore neglectable).

Your exact model is not possible in GPower. If you forget the covariates you can run power calculcations for the condition x time interaction using GPower's F-test-ANOVA-Repeated Measures- Within-Between Interaction. You can check out the R packages pwrss and WebPower, both have also shiny apps that are very easy to use, but I don't think either supports repeated measures setting WITH covariates.

Thank you, I made an edit to clarify there wasn't a time interaction, just a condition. Don't know if this does alter perspectives …

"Time" in my comment was just a placeholder term for the within/repeated element in your design, but I didn't realize you don't have a between-subject factor. In that case you can use GPower's ANOVA -repeated measures-within factors (but only without the covariates). The only way to run a power analysis for a repeated measures design without simulation is to conceptualize it as a repeated measures ANOVA.

The post here is a bit confusing. First, you note that the random effect variance is essentially zero, which to me illustrates that a mixed model is totally unnecessary (more information about what your random effect represents would be helpful, but for now this point alone is important).
Second, you state that simulation is not an option. I can't imagine how simulation isn't an option when it is the most direct way to get your answer. Unlike tools like GPower, one can change literally any piece of the power analysis based off what one would expect from the literature. Since you seem to only really need regression, you can probably set up a simulation like the one I show here to estimate the power, toggling whatever pieces you want and adapting the functions to achieve your goal.
